# How to get whole lot of rows of data from MySql and show it on Java application?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a Mysql database with 100 rows of data in a table. I have created a Java application (Swing) which displays the data in JList, but I am wondering if I load thousands of rows of data, The performance of the app will be reduced right?

If so what is the best way to display the data or query the data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: well, most websites use pagination to bypass that issue. Applications usally know where user is currently within the list and dynamicly fetch "current sight" +/- [NUMBER] row entries so not all of them are displayed/in memory at the same time.

Comment: I didnt try anything now, for now all the 100 rows are showing at once, I am just asking for better method from you guys.

Answer (score 2):

You want to paginate the data, ths is easy to do with MySQL.  Just use the LIMIT and OFFSET in the query.

Comment: Thanks, this will help me start looking at specific place! Thanks a lot :)